# Bubblesort a List of Structs

Tags: c, list, struct

I am trying to fix this issue for a while and cannot find the error. I want to sort a list of structs with bubble sort. I think the error is at the referencing of the pointers.I want to swap the whole structs and not every single data, cause there is much data in a struct so it wouldnt make sense
Kind regards

```
void bubbleSort() 
{ 
    node *tmp;
    node *prev;
    node *ptr1;  

    char c1, c2;
    int cast1, cast2, check=0, i=0;

    if (anfang == NULL) 
        printf("Die Liste wurde nicht initialisiert!\n");

    while(check==0){

        i=0;

        ptr1=anfang;
        prev=ptr1;

        check=1;

        while(ptr1->next!=NULL){

            print(ptr1);
            print(ptr1->next);

            c1=ptr1->vorname[0];
            c2=ptr1->next->vorname[0];
            cast1=(int)c1;
            cast2=(int)c2;

            if(cast1>cast2){

                check=0;
                tmp=ptr1;
                ptr1=ptr1->next; 
                if(i==0)
                    anfang=ptr1;

                tmp->next=ptr1->next;
                ptr1->next=tmp;

                if(i==1)
                    prev->next=ptr1;

                i=1;
                prev=ptr1;
                anfang=prev;
            }
            prev=ptr1;
            ptr1=ptr1->next;
        }
    printf("check:%d\n",check);
    }
}
```

Comment: At first try to rewrite your list implementation without using global variables.

Comment: And the function shall not output any messages.

Comment: I tried it but nothing changed, but should the swap of the pointers work?

Comment: Well, visit this reference  http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-1-0-00000114-000-0-0-1542381535 at my personal forum. Though the message is written in Russian you can translate it using google translate. There are an implementation of a singly-linked list and a corresponding function that implements the bubble sort method.

Comment: We are able to provide more help, but can you provide your entire program?  As Vlad mentioned you should rewrite the program without using global variables. We can't see the rest of your program and it makes it difficult to try to debug and help. So, I would suggest posting the whole program or rewriting the function without globals.